# SSIS Package Query- Count by query

Tags: ssis

I need to create an ssis package to count the no of orders handled by the company and contractor. My input data has two columns related to this and if both the columns match, then it means its by company, else by contractor.
Input table

:[image]

How do i get an output which provides me count based on this logic?

my output should look like this

[image]

pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below approach would be one way of doing it - 
the `ssis` package has taken the data as a sample from oledb and then passed it to `derived column` for performing the column transformation - note the input and output varies which is why we would need the derived column. Once the column transformation is in place we would perform the required aggregate on the row.

Package layout - 
[image]

Derived column -
[image]

Aggregation -
[image]

On a side note: I would prefer these things to be performed on the database itself - which could be accomplished by this simple query -

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT '6/20/2018' AS Date, 'XXX' AS Station, 'XXX' AS WorkLocation, 12345 AS AccountNo UNION ALL
SELECT '6/20/2018' AS Date, 'XXX' AS Station, 'YYY' AS WorkLocation, 12345 AS AccountNo UNION ALL
SELECT '6/20/2018' AS Date, 'XXX' AS Station, 'XXX' AS WorkLocation, 12345 AS AccountNo)
SELECT Date,AccountNo,SUM(CASE WHEN Station = WorkLocation THEN 1 END) AS Company,SUM(CASE WHEN Station != WorkLocation THEN 1 END) AS Contractor 
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Date,AccountNo
```

Comment: I'm getting the same values in both contractor and company. Not sure what the issue is. Can you explain what did you do in derived column for "Company" and "Contractor"?

Comment: The screenshot is self-explanatory, would request to debug your code and check where the issue is. Maybe you have different set of input data.

Comment: My query was to match both the columns and if they match, then it should be flagged as company and if they don't match, then it should be contractor.

Comment: @Shre - and exactly where you have written your query? I don't see any attempts from your end.

Comment: I did try out in SSIS. I did a conditional split based on company/contractor, then aggregated it and tried merge. Merge output was giving me a lot of repetitions. based on your input, i performed it in the query itself using pivot.                  
Select (Column names) from **My Query***                                                           pivot
(count (workdoneby)
for workdoneby in(contractor,company)) as P. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You don;'t need to be that complex - simple derived column for your column transformation and logic would do and then aggregate based on the output would give you your desired result.